Possible to reverse the scrollbar scroll direction?
I want to use middle mouse button to hold and scroll pages like it happens in some photo/video/3D editing apps, where you can drag the page left-right / up-down by holding a certain mouse key like middle mouse button.
The closest thing I can do it in Windows is auto-scroll feature (where you hold middle mouse button and move mouse up or down and it scrolls smoothly). It's not quite same as those apps, but it would still work similar, if I could just reverse the direction. And I guess it's linked to the behavior of scrollbars in the overflowing windows in any apps like browsers (shown in screenshot):

I know that you can change the direction of scroll wheel by using registry, but I couldn't find a way to reverse the scrollbar behavior.
So I would like to know if it's even possible.
Alternatively, if I can't reverse, I would also like to know if it's possible to make auto-scroll scroll by lines (just like normal scroll wheel) instead of being smooth based on pixels. That would also be helpful.

See https://www.functionx.com/vccli/controls/scrollbars.htm on how scrollbars work. One would have to design the application to allow reversing scrollbar behavior. That said, the behavior of the mouse input can be modified, e.g., by free X-Mouse Button Control.
